# Объединение одинаковых данных в коллекции MongoDB (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Имеется коллекция Prices.

```
{
    "slug": "0u-00000124",
    "createdAt": "2017-03-23T14:05:11.934Z",
    "price": 384
},
{
    "slug": "0u-00000125",
    "createdAt": "2017-03-23T14:06:11.934Z",
    "price": 129
},
{
    "slug": "0u-00000125",
    "createdAt": "2017-03-23T14:07:11.934Z",
    "price": 125
}
```

Необходимо сделать выборку по след. условию: при одинаковых slug оставлять только ту запись у которой (createdAt) самая свежая.

Моя реализация через mongoose (сделана сортировка по createdAt) и необходимо дописать условие объединения:

```
Price.find({}, {}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
```

В результате на выходе нужно получить:

```
{
    "slug": "0u-00000124",
    "createdAt": "2017-03-23T14:05:11.934Z",
    "price": 384
},
{
    "slug": "0u-00000125",
    "createdAt": "2017-03-23T14:07:11.934Z",
    "price": 125
}
```